How to upload the best models from lightning_logs checkpoint to huggingface during training after each epoch
I'm training a LayoutLMv3 model for document classification using pytorch-lightning.
While training and testing the model locally I'm facing no issues(able to save the checkpoint and able to load the best model from checkpoints post training).
**Since my training data is very large so training the model will take days to train, My concern is what if something goes wrong with the system. **
Below is what I need:

Upload the lightning_logs checkpoints after each epoch.
How to load the best_model from huggingface using .from_pretrained
Setup the tensorboard on huggingface to see the metric graphs.

FYI:

After the training ends I'm loading best model from local lightning_logs using below code

trained_model = ModelModule.load_from_checkpoint(
    model_checkpoint.best_model_path,
    n_classes=len(DOCUMENT_CLASSES),
    local_files_only=True
)


Pushing model and processor to huggingface

trained_model.model.push_to_hub('repo_name')
processor.push_to_hub('repo_name')


Loading model and processor from huggingface

model = LayoutLMv3ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('repo_name')
processor = LayoutLMv3Processor.from_pretrained('repo_name')

and it works just fine for me.
Below is the ModelModule definition, and trainer code.
class ModelModule(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, n_classes:int):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = LayoutLMv3ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
            "microsoft/layoutlmv3-base",
            num_labels=n_classes
        )
        self.model.config.id2label = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(DOCUMENT_CLASSES)}
        self.model.config.label2id = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(DOCUMENT_CLASSES)}
        self.train_accuracy = Accuracy(task="multiclass", num_classes=n_classes)
        self.val_accuracy = Accuracy(task="multiclass", num_classes=n_classes)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, bbox, pixel_values, labels=None):
        return self.model(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            bbox=bbox,
            pixel_values=pixel_values,
            labels=labels
        )

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
        attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
        bbox = batch["bbox"]
        pixel_values = batch["pixel_values"]
        labels = batch["labels"]
        output = self(input_ids, attention_mask, bbox, pixel_values, labels)
        self.log("train_loss", output.loss)
        self.log(
            "train_acc",
            self.train_accuracy(output.logits, labels),
            on_step=True,
            on_epoch=True
        )
        return output.loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
        attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
        bbox = batch["bbox"]
        pixel_values = batch["pixel_values"]
        labels = batch["labels"]
        output = self(input_ids, attention_mask, bbox, pixel_values, labels)
        self.log("val_loss", output.loss)
        self.log(
            "val_acc",
            self.val_accuracy(output.logits, labels),
            on_step=False,
            on_epoch=True
        )
        return output.loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.00001) #1e-5
        return optimizer
        
        
model_module = ModelModule(len(DOCUMENT_CLASSES))

# Add early stopping
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    min_delta=0.00,
    patience=3,
    verbose=True,
    mode='min'
)


model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    filename="{epoch}-{step}-{val_loss:.4f}", save_last=True, save_top_k=3, monitor="val_loss", mode="min"
)

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    accelerator="gpu",
    precision=16,
    max_epochs=50,
    callbacks=[
        model_checkpoint,
        early_stopping
    ],
)


trainer.fit(model_module, train_data_loader, val_data_loader)```

